# Find a string in array key with regex

Tags: php, regex

***Hello,***

**Question 1 :**

***i need to a translate ( close meaning ) function like this,***

```
$translated_array = array(
    "(.*) Car(.*)" => "is_a_Araba", // "Araba" mean car in english. İts mean this ( in regex ) string mean car.
    "(.*) Apple(.*)" => "is_a_Elma" // "Elma" mean apple in english. İts mean this ( in regex ) string mean apple.
);
```

***İ have a string, like this :***

> "1. Apple, it is awesome."

***İ need if i call function like this;***

```
function_name("1. Apple, it is awesome.", $translated_array) 
this return : "is_a_Elma".

function_name("1. Car, it is awesome.", $translated_array)
this return : "is_a_Araba".
```

**Question 2 :**

```
$translated_array = array(
    "Car name: (.*), (.*) offers." => "This car name is $1, have $2 offers."
);
```

İn function :

```
function_name("Car name: Bugatti, 5 offers.", $translated_array)
this return : "This car name is Bugatti, have 5 offers.".
```

**My tryouts**

**İ know this is a solution for my question but i need faster than this function. Like array_regex("Car name: Bugatti, 5 offers.", $translated_array) ( is example )**

So, i need to dont loop all values for a string. ( have 1000 + translated value. )

```
    foreach($translated_array as $key => $value):
        if(preg_match('/'.$key.'/',$mystring)): return $value; break; endif;
        continue;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: how about `preg_match`

Comment: i tryed, all functions. Not worked for me :(

Comment: You dont show any code of that here!! Update your question with your tryouts.

Comment: And your regex like `(.*) Car(.*)` must used like this in PHP `#(.*) Car(.*)#`.

Comment: And preg_match is used for "search in array". My question"s", "find a string in array with regex".

Comment: Okey, i will update my question in 10 min.

Comment: `And preg_match is used for "search in array". ` Wrong! It matches a part of a string by a given regex within a string. no array involved. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. İ updated my question, can you check ?

Comment: 'And preg_match is used for "search in array". ' İ know, İ mean, preg_match is used for only "search in array" in my question. This function not enough for my question.

Comment: `( have 1000 + translated value. )` writing good code for that issue, makes you an php coding expert `checking n+ strings against n+ matches` ;-) Currently i have no idea.

Comment: Thank You, @JustOnUnderMillions İ trying but i need suggestions for this problem :) i think so, its procrastination for my work :P

Comment: Note: `"(.*) Car(.*)"` will match "1. Cart, is .." also as `car`. Thing your question is way to big/komplex for get it answered here. Read about "PHPHUnit Tests" and code your solution testdriven to get it fast as possible

Comment: İts a example. İ need to find or search a string in "regex'ed" array keys. İ dont have a problem in my array or regex keys. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small function that will search for a match against a regular expression and each array index and then returns the value if a match is found. Something along these lines:

```
function arrayFindKey($expr, array $array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match($expr, $key)) {
      return $value;
    }
  }
}

$array = array(
  "1. Apple, it is awesome." => "is_a_Elma",
  "1. Car, it is awesome." => "is_a_Araba",
);
print arrayFindKey("/(.*) Apple(.*)/", $array);
```

I guess you could also try to use a single string to search for a match, doing something like this:

```
function arrayFindKey($expr, array $array) {
  // each key is separated by a '#' character
  $keys = '#' . implode('#', array_keys($array)) . '#' ;
  $matches = [];
  // if a match is found then index 1 will hold the key
  if (preg_match('/#(' . $expr . ')#/', $keys, $matches)) {
     return $array[$matches[1]];
  }
}
```

Notice that you need to exclude the `#` character since it is used as a separator between each array key:

```
print arrayFindKey("[^#]+Apple[^#]+", $array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. İ updated my question, can you check ?

Comment: İ have a string like this : "1. Apple, it is awesome." Not ""/(.*) Apple(.*)/"," :(

Comment: And i have, 1000 + value in my array. İts not a solution for me. Because slower than other functions :(

Comment: @MertO. - I don't know if it will work in your specific case, but I added an alternate solution. I would believe this needs to be tweeked, but it might give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you again. İ will try. :)